# Asp.Net - User Control Button OnClick Event Not Firing

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control that is loaded only in certain instances, for example, when a user clicks a button on the page the following happens:

```
MyControl ctl = (MyControl)LoadControl(controlPath);
this.MyFormControl.Add(ctl);
```

The user control that is loaded has a form and a submit button, with a method that I want to run on click so:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SaveButton" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

In the codebehind of the user control:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

I can't seem to get the do something part to happen when the button is clicked.  I think it may be related to the fact that the control is not normally loaded with the page, but I'm not really sure what to do about that.

Comment: Please give a better description of how you are adding the Button to the page.

Comment: MyControl ctl = (MyControl)LoadControl(controlPath);  this.MyFormControl.Add(ctl);  This happens as part of a method that is running after a button on the page is clicked.

Comment: Does btnSave_Click exist in the code-behind for the User Control or the page you are adding the UC to?

Comment: in the code-behind for the user control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this in your page directive?:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
```

Edit

Is it dynamically created/loaded? Dynamic controls need to be created every request (maybe it's in a if (!IsPostback) block)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is the issue, but I'm not really sure what to do about it.  It seems impractical to dynamically load the control after the postback.  Is there a good way around this?

Comment: Sadly, no, you have to create the dynamic control with each request.

Comment: +1 on the "(maybe it's in a if (!IsPostback) block)"

Answer (score 0):

Is Viewstate enabled on your page?

If you specifically turned it off, you will need to re-add your usercontrol on each post back as the page won't automatically re-add it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had viewstate="false" on the page I was adding the control to. (on the aspx page)